# Why is there a lack of correlation between the global usage of oil and the price of oil?

Tags: investing, commodities, government

The list below illustrates the world's usage of oil and it's respective average price for that year. Given that the global demand for oil is rather inelastic what explains the large disconnect between the actual usage of oil and its price?  On the surface it seems the physical market for oil is not aligned with the "paper" market for oil.  Is there a general belief inside of the professional investment community that the market is manipulated by either governments or large money institutions to drive the price in a particular direction?

```
**Global Usage**       **Average Price**
2015 - 92.39 mbpd   $44.50 per barrel 
2014 - 91.39 mbpd   $89.08 per barrel
2013 - 90.49 mbpd   $91.17 per barrel
2012 - 86.15 mbpd   $86.46 per barrel
2011 - 84.21 mbpd   $87.04 per barrel
2010 - 81.26 mbpd   $71.21 per barrel
2009 - 83.27 mbpd   $53.48 per barrel
2008 - 86.05 mbpd   $91.48 per barrel

mbpd = million barrels per day
Source : http://labs.timogrossenbacher.ch/worldoil/
         http://inflationdata.com/Inflation/Inflation_Rate/Historical_Oil_Prices_Table.asp
    Value supplied for 2015 usage is estimated.
```

Comment: I'd also note that, given that you know demand is rather inelastic, why would you expect demand and price to be linked?  Inelastic demand means supply (or other factors) determine price, not demand.

Comment: Yes, supply is the other factor, it's not clear though that this is about personal finance, it appears to be a question about economics.

Comment: Supply is not the only other factor (the cost of production, for example), hence my hedge.

Answer (score 2):

Largely that is because global usage of oil is relatively stable - you show a range between 81mbpd and 92mbpd, which is pretty stable considering prices fluctuate in a range of roughly 2x - and much of the fluctuation in demand is due to price sensitivity of a sector of the demand, not the other way around, or is entirely unrelated to price.  Most of the demand for oil is price-insensitive, and so the effect of that demand on price is constant.

Most of the fluctuation of oil price is related to two things: supply, and worries over Middle East stability.  OPEC used to substantially control its member nations' supply levels; this kept prices reasonably high, as it meant the US and other western countries would need to extract more expensive oil to make up the difference, or reduce consumption for the relatively small portion of our oil demand that is price sensitive.  Because OPEC for many years was effectively a monopolist supplier of oil, they could determine the price level by altering supply to keep it at the same level - not dissimilar to how some countries peg their currencies.  For the Middle East, oil is basically their currency.

You're also looking at a very particular time period, where 2008 through 2010 was a global recession, driving down demand, which did lower prices for a while.  Then prices returned to their 'new normal' levels (80s-90s), until the recent drop began (which is for various reasons, including technological, but largely is still supply-side).

Comment: you beat me to it! I wonder if you could correlate price to number of political events in the Middle East / across all oil producing countries...

Comment: @MD-Tech The problem is that it would be a case by case thing, and highly subjective, since there's no objective measure of 'how bad a political event is in terms of oil prices'.  Arab Spring had some effect, clearly, but honestly not as much as some would have thought; really, the first Iraq war and 9/11 were the two biggest - and part of that was undoubtedly the fact that one of the larger oil producers was largely removed from the game.  (Interestingly, the Iranian embargo doesn't seem to have had all that much effect - I guess Saudi et al just has that much oil.)

Comment: I realize that severity of the event is subjective but I'm looking (literally right now!) for a data source that just gives the total number. Perhaps weighting by the country's oil production for that year.